# How to resolve findjobj in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

On searching I found this.
"The function findjobj is not a built-in function. It is user-contributed function available on the Mathworks File Exchange."
My question is how to avoid or bypass this error in my program?
(I am somewhat new to matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download findjobj [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) and then put it in Matlab search path so it's accessible to the scripts your run.

More info about the search path [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html).

Hope that helps!